# Odd PHP Code To Display HTML Of Meta Box

Tags: custom-field, metabox

I'm trying to use [`add_meta_box()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) to create meta information for my custom post type. So far it's fine, but I don't understand why the `$callback` looks the way it does.

An [example from one WordPress tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/) is this:

```
/* Display the post meta box. */
function callback( $post ) { ?>

  <?php wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'smashing_post_class_nonce' ); ?>

  <p>
    <label for="smashing-post-class"><?php _e( "Add a custom CSS class, which will be applied to WordPress' post class.", 'example' ); ?></label>
    <br />
    <input class="widefat" type="text" name="smashing-post-class" id="smashing-post-class" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'smashing_post_class', true ) ); ?>" size="30" />
  </p>
<?php }
```

What's up with `?>` (in line two) and `<?php}` (in the last line)? I don't understand.

Can I just echo out HTML instead of doing that? How does WordPress display the HTML if it is just typed raw within a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes when working with a larger block of HTML it is easier to just close your PHP tags and type the HTML directly instead of trying to `echo` your HTML within PHP. Yes, you should be able to `echo` your HTML as well.

Edit: I want to take a closer look at the context from your [example](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/) because it is more common in WordPress to do this within a theme than within a function, as is the case here. From the tutorial:

> You still need to display the meta box’s HTML though. That’s where the
>   smashing_post_class_meta_box() function comes in ($callback parameter
>   from above).

Then the code example you posted is displayed and further explained:

> What the above function does is display the HTML output for your meta
>   box. It displays a hidden nonce input. It then displays an input element for adding
>   a custom post class as well as output the custom class if one has been
>   input.

Ok, that's great, but to understand why we are able to write HTML this way in our function we need to go back to the previous step in the tutorial where we actually add the meta box:

```
/* Create one or more meta boxes to be displayed on the post editor screen. */
function smashing_add_post_meta_boxes() {

  add_meta_box(
    'smashing-post-class',      // Unique ID
    esc_html__( 'Post Class', 'example' ),    // Title
    'smashing_post_class_meta_box',   // Callback function
    'post',         // Admin page (or post type)
    'side',         // Context
    'default'         // Priority
  );
}
```

You can see here that when adding the meta box, we have the callback function from your question named `smashing_post_class_meta_box`. **It is only because the function `smashing_post_class_meta_box` is hooked to this specific meta box that the HTML is parsed here.** If you just ran the function `smashing_post_class_meta_box` randomly, it would not be displayed at all as it would likely be running prior to WordPress init.

Comment: Weird... never seen it done that way before. Thank you.

Comment: I've seen it a lot; both within and outside of WordPress. It's a common technique with PHP.

Comment: It's more straightforward in a static theme template. Isn't this particular example a bit less common in that the HTML is directly dumped within a callback function? I don't think the function is even returning the HTML. It's just dumping it directly because the function is called as such a specific place. Do you happen to know of any examples like this outside of the WordPress framework?